# Lazy Initialization sounds and works great. Why not always default to using lazy initialization?

Tags: swift, initialization, lazy-loading, lazy-initialization

Seems like lazy initialization is great. I understand the concept and have tested on my code and I don't see any lags. Then the question is, why not always use lazy initialization? What's the drawback to this? What am I not being aware of?

Comment: one of the drawbacks is that it can't be immutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this example of a `lazy var`:

```
struct S {
    lazy var lazyVar: Int = { /* compute some value */ 0 }()
}
```

What really happens behind the scenes is something like this:

```
struct S {
    var _lazyVar: Int? = nil

    var lazyVar: Int {
        mutating get {
            if let existingValue = _lazyVar {
                return existingValue
            }
            else {
                let newlyComputedValue = /* compute some value */ 0
                _lazyVar = newlyComputedValue
                return newlyComputedValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you see, every access of `lazyVar` requires a branch, to check if there's a value already, or if it's necessary to compute one for the first time. This adds overhead that easily outweighs the benefit of lazily evaluating values with simple (fast) derivations.

Comment: You want a `mutating` getter, e.g `var lazyVar: Int { mutating get {...} }` :) This of course highlights another drawback with `lazy`; it requires the mutability of the instance it's accessed on. (Hey, congrats on the gold [swift] badge btw!)

Answer (score 3):

One of the biggest drawbacks of `lazy` is that `lazy` variables cannot be a constant. This drawback will eventually eliminate a lot of cases where you have to declare certain variables as `let`.

In terms of readability, when other developers read your code and saw `lazy` implementations, as a developer, I will straight away know that either this variable is running something intensive, or this variable requires some value from another source before this can be computed.